# Using php laravel i want to create a product using shopify API

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

simply am using **laravel** i want to be able to make an application in laravel
 which can **create a product** using the shopfy api ,
 so please is there any thing that can help me to do this / **A package or a tutorial** ,
 as i can't find anything about shopify with laravel or even php , 
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

First, you need this package for grab the api

> https://github.com/ixudra/curl

or better you can used this package

> https://packagist.org/packages/shopifyextras/shopify-php-api-wrapper

You can find another package in there...

that's my recomendation for api shopify